# Extracting specific information using iterator and re python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, iterator

I have a program which tells me who will have their birthday today.
I have names and birthdays stored in a text file called `data.txt`.
Here is a sample of data.txt:

```
Master 13/12 
Monkey 16/06
Michael 16/06
mike  01/05
Minita 24/06
Mom 12/06
```

And here is the program :

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time

logic = time.strftime("%d/%m")
err_occur = []                        
pattern = re.compile(logic, re.IGNORECASE)
try:
    with open ('data.txt', 'rt') as in_file:         
        for linenum, line in enumerate(in_file):        
            if pattern.search(line) != None:         
                err_occur.append((linenum, line.rstrip('\n')))
                for linenum, line in err_occur:             
                    print("Line ", linenum, ": ", line, sep='')
except IOError:
    print ("data.txt Not found")
```

If I run this program and if today's date is 16/06, its output should be

```
Line 3: Monkey 16/06
Line 4: Michael 16/06
```

However The output it shows me is only

```
Line 3: Monkey 16/06
```

I guess the `for...in` statement aren't valid?
Shouldn't they work in a loop?

It has only been some days since I have been learning python. I do not fully understand iterators yet. Hence, it would be really helpful if you could explain my mistake in layman terms.

EDIT- Thank you @zwer for pointing out my mistake and @Coldspeed for providing a much more efficient solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simpler way to get those matching lines one by one. You can use `re.finditer`. It returns a generator of matches:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re
import time

s = open('data.txt', 'rt').read()

logic = time.strftime("%d/%m")
err_occur = []                        
for m in re.finditer('(.*?)[\s]*' + logic, s, re.M | re.IGNORECASE):
    print(m.group(0))
```

Output

```
Monkey 16/06
Michael 16/06
```

This won't give you the `Line x` in the output. If you want that, you may need to change things up a bit.

Comment: Considering that I would be putting all the birthdates in `data.txt`, I do not think this method will work. Hence I suggest you to change your first line to `s = open('data.txt', 'rt').read()`    EDIT- I just saw you already did that

Comment: @HellfireCharchitPb Done.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing a double loop when reading the file? If you want to build it your way, just print out the matching line:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re
import time

logic = time.strftime("%d/%m")
err_occur = []
pattern = re.compile(logic, re.IGNORECASE)
try:
    with open ('data.txt', 'rt') as in_file:
        for linenum, line in enumerate(in_file):
            if pattern.search(line) != None:
                line = line.rstrip("\n")
                print("Line ", linenum + 1, ": ", line, sep='')
                err_occur.append((linenum + 1, line))
except IOError:
    print ("data.txt Not found")

# Line 2: Monkey 16/06
# Line 3: Michael 16/06
```